Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string - but same approach works for different table with same data format
I have a column of dates formatted in YYYYMMDD format and I am using the below statement to convert them to a specific Date format:
cast (convert(date, convert (varchar, DDC.src_create_dt), 112) as date)  'Created Date'
I get the error outlined in the title, which is odd as I use the same approach on another table, where it works flawlessly.
I have inspected the entire column in the new table for any obvious errors or null values, but all the dates are populated and there are no discrepancies I can see.
Any ideas why this might not be working or if there is another way to achieve the conversion?

"I have a column of dates formatted in YYYYMMDD format" That there is the real problem; you are storing dates as a string not as a date. Fix your design. Because of the poor design, you almost certainly have some values that aren't valid dates, like '20230229' or '20241342'.

convert (varchar, DDC.src_create_dt) This achieves nothing; your column DDC.src_create_dt is already a varchar. At "worst" it'll truncate it to a varchar(30) (Bad Habits to Kick : Declaring VARCHAR without (length)).

Use try_convert to see which non null "date" values generate null results

Run select your_so_called_date from yourtable where try_convert(date, your_so_called_date) is null to get all invalid "dates" from your table, see https://dbfiddle.uk/YiVUJTyI

Dates have no format, they're binary values. Never, ever store them as text. There's no way to even guess what such a string contains. There's no way to enforce that all those strings will have the same format.

it works flawlessly no it doesn't, you just didn't notice the errors yet. Which is far worse than an error. It means you may be mistaking April 7th for July 4th without realizing it. Bugs like this are behind the $1M electricity bills you read in the news from time to time.

Not to mention getting arrested due to an incorrect date format

Apart from your biggest problem, storing values in the wrong format, you should also consider that converting a value to a certain format is not to be done in sql, but in your client application

Dates have no format in a database, I am not just talking about datetime or any other type, I am just saying that how your data is shown/formatted is in my opinion not a task of the database

@Boris what's the actual type of the src_create_dt column? Post the CREATE TABLE script. It's quite possible the problem is caused by the conversion. One conversion uses a specific format but the other uses whatever the current locale is. If you wanted to truncate the time component, cast(src_create_dt as date) would be enough.

@ThomA the first conversion doesn't use 112. On my machine select convert(varchar,getdate()) returns Sep  4 2024  2:54PM. That's the default format according to the CONVERT docs. Strangely, select convert(datetime,'Sep  4 2024  2:58PM',...) or convert(date ignore most specifiers. It doesn't matter whether you use 1, 112 or 113. Only 130 and 131 fail

We still don't know what datatype src_create_dt is. It may even be an int storing these 20240904 etc values`

AHH shoot, you're right @PanagiotisKanavos , I miss read the code. Now that CONVERT confuses me even more.


I have a column of dates formatted in YYYYMMDD

To be more precise, you have a text columm containing date strings in this expected format.  As @Thom A mentioned in his comments, maybe not all text is in this format. Could you run:
SELECT src_create_dt
FROM yourTable
WHERE src_create_dt NOT LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]';

You could also use TRY_CONVERT() and check for null conversions:
SELECT src_create_dt
FROM yourTable
WHERE TRY_CONVERT(date, src_create_dt) IS NULL

However, this might not catch all bad data.  For example, 20242009 might validate, even though this date is actually YYYYDDMM and is bogus as YYYYMMDD.

"As @Larnu mentioned in his comments" I haven't used that alias on [so] for a couple years.

I like to add: AND src_create_dt IS NOT NULL to filter out false positives

It's also possible that the error is caused by the conversions, even though src_create_dt is a valid date type. There are 2 conversions (and a bogus one), one using the default locale (and just varchar) and 1 specifying YYYYMMDD. The final one tries to cast the date value to date. Perhaps all the OP needs is cast(src_created_dt as date)

Hi @ThomA,
I added the NOT LIKE condition to the data as I was already extracting it and it came back with 0 results.
I have also had a manual review of the data, cannot spot any that would be a bogus date, they're all YYYYMMDD from what I can see.

Is your table actually a view? Which uses some manipulations?

@siggemannen the "IS NOT NULL" is not relevant as there are no gaps in data. I have tried TRY_CONVERT but get the same result as with the original statement.
And no, this is a table, not a view. I have no influence over the structure of the data as it's managed on corporate level.
So far still trying to find a solution for this as all the dates are formatted in such a manner in our company and this is the first time I am running into this problem.

What is the exact TRY_CONVERT query you're running? Unfortunately, i don't think you're TRY_CONVERTING in the right place
